# Зачем нужен index.js для компонентов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В процессе изучения React наткнулся на множество примеров в которых присутствует следующая структура:

```
├─ src/components/ExampleComponent
   ├── ExampleComponent.js 
   ├── ExampleComponent.test.js 
   ├── index.js
```

И так для каждого компонента. ExampleComponent.js и ExampleComponent.test.js  у меня вопросов не вызывают, однако index.js остается загадкой. Причем файлик содержит везде одно и то же и выглядит по принципу:
export { default } from './ExampleComponent';

В чем смысл?

Comment: index.js, например, позволяет уменьшить вложенность при импорте

Answer (score 9, accepted):

К примеру у вас есть папка `customBtn` внутри с файлом `customBtn.jsx`.

Если импортировать файл `customBtn.jsx`  из папки components (без index.js)  надо будет написать так.

```
import CustomBtn from "./components/customBtn/customBtn";
```

Если добавить `index.js` внутри папки `customBtn` то не надо будет два раза подряд написать `/customBtn/customBtn`

```
import CustomBtn from "./components/customBtn";
```

Это не обязательно так писать если вам удобно можете написать дважды имя папки и файла.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ваш пример прекрасно передал мне суть.

Comment: @Tankred всегда пожалуйста :)